# Creating new columns and converting to and from binary value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with two columns, PORT1 and PORT2, I am trying to convert each column to binary value and calculating a new value with some rules.

Example:

```
PORT1 = 16
PORT2=1
```

1. first calculating binary value for PORT1+1=17 and PORT2-1=0, I must have that with len og eight integer :
   **00010001** and **00000000**
2. Then converting to integer this number : 010**00010001**0000**00000000**000000000

My final column will be 1109393408

I tried to do this but it saying that it can't interpret a series like an integer.

```
DF['new_column'] = int('010'+bin(DF['PORT1']+1)[2:].zfill(8)+'0000'+bin(DF['PORT2']-1)[2:].zfill(8)+'000000000',2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is ok but you need to use `apply` function:

```
DF['new_column'] = DF.apply(lambda row: int('010'+bin(row['PORT1']+1)[2:].zfill(8)+'0000'+bin(row['PORT2']-1)[2:].zfill(8)+'000000000',2), axis= 1)
```

Output:

```
   PORT1    PORT2   new_column
0   16      1       1109393408
```